# Menu font background color is white

Tags: themes, menu, panel

Something happened to my theme (I guess) where all the menu's font background color is white. This is for all menus, right click mouse menu and that top menu bar. I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying it out. I was following some instructions on changing themes ...something about installing gnome 3.4. And now my menu's are all messed up. When I try and use Ubuntu Tweak to change the theme it won't let me select a different one. It's just stuck on Ambient. I saw the setting to unlock themes but that doesn't help. The option menu pops up with the list of different themes but I am not able to select any. I would take a screen shot but the print screen button does not work when I have a menu open.

Heh I'm not even sure I'm asking this correctly. I have done some reading on the gtk-3.0.css and unity.css files. I'm not sure if they were edited or not, could some one post the default files for me?

Comment: I had the same problem few days ago (after an update), and today when I installed updates, it was fixed. Such bugs arise but Ubuntu is quick in resolving them. :)

Answer (score 1):

To find the problem and a solution this might have to be done in steps.

The first step is to try and reset unity.  You can use myunity to do this.  To install it, open a terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T).  Now type:

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

From the terminal run:

```
myunity
```

At the top you should see a menu.  Select Theme.  Now click on "default settings".  Note, you can click on each item in the menu and click "default settings" to reset everything.

Logout and log back in.

Is the problem fixed?  If so, your good-to-go.  If not try step two.

The second step is to create a new user and login as that user and see if you have the same problem.

Open System Settings and go to User Accounts.  Click the Unlock button and enter your password.  Now click the plus icon to create a new user.  After you add the user click on Password and enter a password twice.  Now logout and login as this new user.

Is the problem solved?  If not, send me a message and I will continue to work with you to get this fixed.

Best,

Jim4Prez

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up giving up and just reinstalled Ubuntu. I wasn't able to even switch themes, it was stuck on Ambiance. I hadn't gotten to the point of even switching themes. I was following steps to install gnome 3.4 so I could install some new themes and widgets? on the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is  a broken theme.

Thisi happens when the theme in question does not support Gnom 3.4.

You can do:

1. Get in conctact with the author of the theme and notify him of this.
2. Try to fix the Theme yourself
3. Get a compatible Gnome 3.4 Theme

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't even get to the point of switching themes. I was following instructions to install gnome 3.4. The theme was stuck on Ambiance. I saw the other themes but I wasn't able to switch to them.