# When I use some themes my menu tabs become white. How can I fix it?

Tags: lubuntu, themes

[image]

When I use some themes my menu tabs become white. I'm having this problem with many themes, can anybody help?

Comment: I think that is built into the theme, you might be able to edit the theme. Just go into the theme file and look for the text file for the theme. Maybe xml maybe not. Edit this file.

Comment: Also, if you like dark themes, delorean dark and sable work well but I haven't tested either one on  lubuntu. Some older delorean themes had this problem but the newer versions seem to have fixed this.

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153290/menu-font-background-color-is-white) for any idea!

Comment: as @mchid says, the "white" is a feature not a bug. The relevant file would be your theme's gtkrc file. It's plain text. Or just use an appropriate dark theme! I don't know of any theme which selectively allows you to color tabs alone. Mostly, the color set for tabs is used elsewhere as well.

Comment: Sable-Red-NP-3.14 is similar

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you installed this theme, the control file could be in one of the following directories:

```
/usr/share/themes/Numix/
```

or

```
~/.themes/Numix
```

Now, assuming Lubuntu uses the openbox-3 theme settings from numix: the config file should be either here:

```
/usr/share/themes/Numix/openbox-3/themerc
```

or

```
~/.themes/Numix/openbox-3/themerc
```

You will have to figure out which value to change and what to change it to.

Also, it could be one of the color settings in your `.gtkrc` file or `/usr/share/themes/Numix/gtk-3.0/gtk-dark.css` or something similar.

All color values are in hex values from **000000**, which is red **00** green **00** blue **00** (black), all the way up to **ffffff**, which is red **ff** green **ff** blue **ff** (white).

0123456789abcdef

It looks like **dcdcdc** might be the one you need to change but i'm not sure because that one was for alot of text IDK. Use something like gimp to figure out the color values.

---

also, on xubuntu, you can set those to show only the icon of the windows instead of the icon and title like you have shown